# Cartan subalgebras of a loop algebra.

Tags: lie-algebras

For an algebraically closed field $\mathbb F$ of characteristic zero, a  finite-dimensional Lie algebra $\frak G$ has a Cartan subalgebra and these subalgebras are conjugated in a certain sense.

Let $L(\frak G)= \frak G\otimes \mathbb F[t,t^{-1}]$ be the loop algebra associated to $\frak G$ with the natural bracket. Does exist a Cartan subalgebra for $L(\frak G)$? How to describe it?

Comment: WHat is your definition of a Cartan algebra in this general situation?

Comment: Are you the same Matt as in http://math.stackexchange.com/users/22623/matt ? Are you having problems logging in?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have no idea why my login is not working. I am a new user, but I'm definitely going badly.